# dimple js event handler chart data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I have a bar chart with `dimple js` and I set event that when ever a bar clicked some thing happen but I want the data of that specific bar that has been clicked and which bar clicked how can I get that
here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92mLvecp/1/)
here is my sample js code :

```
data = [
        { "Value" : 10, "Year" : 2009},
        { "Value" : 11, "Year" : 2011},
        { "Value" : 12, "Year" : 2007},
        { "Value" : 13, "Year" : 2006},
        { "Value" : 14, "Year" : 2014},
        { "Value" : 15, "Year" : 2012},
        { "Value" : 16, "Year" : 2011},
        { "Value" : 17, "Year" : 2013},
        { "Value" : 18, "Year" : 2015}
    ];
   var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 600, 400);
   var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
   var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Year");
    x.addOrderRule("Year");
    var y = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Value");
    chart.addColorAxis("Value", ["blue", "purple", "red"]);
    var lines = chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
    lines.lineWeight = 4;
    lines.lineMarkers = true;
    chart.ease = "bounce";
    chart.staggerDraw = true;
    chart.draw(1000);



 d3.selectAll("rect").on("click", function (e) {
        ///I want to know which bar clicked here 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event object `e`. I have consoled `e` where you can find the different values. I got the value at x-axis and y-axis with `e.cx` and `e.cy` respectively.

```
 d3.selectAll("rect").on("click", function (e) {
        ////Which chart clicked
     console.log(e);
     $('p').html('Selected: x-axis -'+e.cx+', y-axis -'+e.cy);

    });
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/92mLvecp/3/)

Comment: @aspsmn how to use above events when we use multiple chart on the page